# series of integrals of functions is abs. convergent implies series of functions converges almost everywhere

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I’m finding these types of questions hard to follow. This type of question always seem to utilise Chebyshev’s inequality to prove the series of functions is absolutely convergent almost everywhere.

[image]

I would like to know in particular why the values $4^{-k}$ chosen and $2^{-k}$ were chosen in the proof and why was a ‘bracketed series’ $\sum g_k$ was introduced.

It all seems a bit random and so I don’t have the intuition to apply it to other similar questions.